# Quantum Entanglement and Two clocks

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity

I was reading this [article](http://www.sciencealert.com/scientists-have-set-a-limit-for-quantum-entanglement-and-it-s-really-freaking-powerful) about an experiment to limit quantum entanglement. I'm a high school student and I admit that I maybe lacking some context regarding this query. I know that quantum entanglement in which quantum states of two or more objects have to be described in reference to each other.

My question was **If both photon sources are used to sync clocks (without breaking the entanglement) local to them and one clock/particle pair accelerate away from earth at $30g$, will both the clocks slow down as the pair under acceleration approach the speed of light?**

Comment: Came here to ask the same question. Nobody has an answer?

Comment: Here might be what are you looking for: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293546/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is quantum entanglement affected by time dilation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293546/)